# Последовательная сортировка массива JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно отсортировать массив, чтобы [A-Z] были первыми, [a-z] вторыми, а все остальное внизу.

```
const data = [word, Word, 123, #$$@, work432]

      const nextData = data.sort((a: any) => {
        if (a.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
          return 1;
        } else if (a.match(/[a-z]/)) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      });
```

Comment: `ZazA` -> `AZaz` или `ZazA` -> `ZAaz` ? Нужно ли A-Z и a-z между собой сортировать или просто A-Z вперед, а a-z после ?

Comment: @uber42 сначала идут элемент по алфавиту через a-z заглавную, потом алфавит по прописной, потом все остальное что есть в массиве